# certain file extensions always appear disabled viewing Google Drive through iOS’s picker

Tags: google-drive-api

We’re using iOS’s UIDocumentMenuViewController/UIDocumentPickerViewController APIs, but this problem happens only with Google Drive, so I’ll start here. If you think we should send Apple a bug report instead, let me know.

In our app or a minimal single-view app, we show the document menu and then the picker. When we view Google Drive, files with certain extensions (iges, sldprt, stl) always appear disabled. Other common extensions (tiff, jpg) and CAD-related extensions (sat, x_t, step) work fine.

This happens whether the file is empty, contains a JPG, contains CAD data, etc.

It doesn’t happen with Dropbox -- only with Google Drive.

[Here’s a shot of how Drive looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glmmF.png) and below some (minimal, I hope) sample code.

Thanks,

-- Mike

```
- (void)pick {
UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu =
    [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeItem]
                                                         inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
importMenu.delegate = self;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:importMenu];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)
                           inView:self.view
         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                         animated:YES];
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Since this works with both the built-in iCloud Drive picker I fear this is a bug in the Google Drive picker. They have to make sure to test conformance to the passed-in UTI by creating a tag from the file extension via UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag; then they have to check whether that UTI conforms to one of the requested ones.

As an aside, your way of presenting the view controller in the code sample is highly unidiomatic. A nicer way would be the following:

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeItem] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
...

[self presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
```

This gets rid of the ugly if(idiom) statement.

Comment: Apple confirms this is a bug in Google Drive. Microsoft’s OneDrive is worse. Box seems to fall down, too.   Google, are you listening? I posted here because you said you monitor this tag…